# QuickBooks Enterprise 14 doesn't call registered SDK events

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We have a QuickBooks plugin application based on qbXml approach, that subscribes for the several events(data, ui, uiextentions) of QuickBooks application to process its data. It worked properly for the QuickBooks versions 11.0, 12.0, 13.0.

Now we've got QuickBooks Enterprise 14 Beta on testing. It successfully subscribes to events, but QuickBooks application doesn't call any of them, also UiExtention items don't show up in the File menu.
Please help me figure out what changed in the new version and how to make it work.

P.S. I attached [Logs File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipoqhf89nj5g731/logs.txt) with QuickBooks session logs 
- my qbxml requests/responces for the ui extention event subscription
- qbxml check requests/responces to check that subscriptions are persisted.
- last strange rows from the qbsdklog.txt

Answer (score 0):

Please submit a support ticket and include any logs you have.